# struts2 multiple @validation in class

Tags: java, validation, struts2

the below is the code for login class that i am using, first validation is used to check the username and password
the second validation is used when the user wants to change his password.

> the problem i am facing is they are in same class and when i am trying to login, 2 validation is being triggered and looking for old password and new password.

when i remove the second validation, its working fine.

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {
@Validations(
            emails = {
                @EmailValidator(fieldName = "username",key = "invalid.email.id") 
            },
            requiredStrings = {
                @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName = "username", trim = true, key = "username.required"),
                @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName = "password", trim = false, key = "password.required")
            },
            stringLengthFields = {
                @StringLengthFieldValidator(fieldName = "username",trim = true, key = "username.length.exceed"),
                @StringLengthFieldValidator(fieldName = "password",trim = false, key = "password.length.exceed"),
            }
    )
    public String login() {}

@Validations(
            requiredStrings = {
                @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName = "oldPassword", trim = true, key = "oldpassword.required"),
                @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName = "password", trim = false, key = "password.required"),
                @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName = "confirmPassword", trim = false, key = "newpassword.required")
            }
    )
    public String changePassword() {}}
```

Cant we use multiple validations for multiple properties in same class?

Comment: Could you post details how do you use this code?

Comment: @RomanC, the code i have added is what i am using. I have added validations for 2 different methods login and changePassword. password field is common for login and changepassword, and old/new password are  required for change password. The problem with login is it doesnt have old/new password and unable to login.

Comment: the code is not enough.